# How to extract elements from nested list in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, nested-lists

I'm working with json data which I've converted into a tibble with some list columns. I'm trying to extract the useful information from the list columns but am facing issues. If given the following dataset-

```
mydf <-tibble( 
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = list(list(list(id="id1", title="title1"), list(id="id11", title="title11")), 
           list(id="id2",title="title2"), 
           NULL)
)
```

How can I convert it into the following-

```
data.frame(x=c(1:3), id = c("id1;id11", "id2", ""), title = c("title1;title11", "title2", ""))

#  x       id          title
#1 1 id1;id11 title1;title11
#2 2      id2         title2
#3 3
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are better ways, but this is what I can do for now. For each row, I extracted strings and concatenated them with `toString()`. Since `unnest()` creates multiple rows for each row (i.e., 1, 2, and 3 in x), I used `summarize()` to temporarily combine strings. Then, I separate them using `separate()`.

```
mydf %>% 
unnest(y, keep_empty = TRUE) %>% 
rowwise %>% 
mutate(y = toString(unlist(y))) %>%
group_by(x) %>% 
summarize(string = paste(y, collapse = "_")) %>% 
separate(col = string, into = c("id", "title"), sep = "_")

#      x id          title        
#  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>        
#1     1 id1, title1 id11, title11
#2     2 id2         title2       
#3     3 ""          NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If the names are consistent as in the example, you can do:

```
mydf2 <- unlist(mydf)
x <- mydf2[grepl("x", names(mydf2))]
id <- mydf2[grepl("id", names(mydf2))]
title <- mydf2[grepl("title", names(mydf2))]
tibble(x, id, title)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     id    title  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 1     id1   title1 
2 2     id11  title11
3 3     id2   title2
```